# How to install wordpress on MS SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to convert my wordpress site which is based on MYSQl to a MS SQL because my we have our main database through MS SQL and we are creating database driven wordpress sites.  I have been able to automate all of our wordpress installation + setup through database scripts through MYSQL but all of our variables + inputs are in MS SQL.

Would it be easier to create a new database in MYSQL and migrate all of my data over from MS SQL or is there a way to have wordpress use MS SQL.  I am wondering if anyone has been able to do this or has any hints.  Thanks

EDIT/UPDATE: I have accomplished this by using a linked server. [Here](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/) is a website if anyone else is reading this and wants to run the wordpress database by using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

Comment: http://projectnami.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Even when migrating the data over Wordpress would still use MySQL specific API calls and MySQL specific SQL statements, you'd first have to refactor the whole codebase in order to make it compatible.

Comment: Because of this is there a way to then have wordpress use MS SQL?

Comment: You just need to change all MySQL function for those of MS SQL and it should work... But the queries needs to be changed, the PHP files, some functions, etc. It has been not made for MS SQL for a reason! ;)

Comment: @johannes, we've refactored WP Core to support MSSQL. You can find it here: https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami

Comment: We actually can: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-database-abstraction/

Comment: http://projectnami.org/

Comment: Well, yes you can with projectnami.org, the core is stable, but there is no control over plugins.  Spending eternities figuring which plugin does work and which one doesn't isn't really worth it.  I have tested for a year, and am tired of having to do manual patches for mySQL code in plugins.  If you can dedicate someone; go for it.  If you need it to work without too much babysitting; don't.

Comment: Microsoft says you can: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/05/12/running-wordpress-on-sql-server/

Answer (score 11):

It is definitely possible to run WordPress connecting to MS SQL Server. We are running such an instance in production at my company. Here are two posts that describe the process of using WordPress with MS SQL Server and IIS. I am using such a configuration right now on my local box.

http://techsugar.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/how-to-install-wordpress-on-iis-7-5-using-sql-server-2008/

http://wordpress.visitmix.com/development/installing-wordpress-on-sql-server

Comment: Althought this could work for somebody, the wpdb abstraction plugin  is no longer being developed for over 2 years so I strongly recommend not using it, since lots of the queries are not translated causing approx 20 errors in average.

Answer (score 1):

There is no feasible way to do this. MS SQL support is an open request in WordPress's [**bug tracking system.**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10918)

[**Here**](http://www.ixalon.net/2008/10/wordpress-and-microsoft-sql-server/) is a blog entry from a guy who tried it. It didn't end well.

For completeness's sake, there seems to be an *approach* that is in alpha Stadium  (Not suitable for everyday use!) that may one day become a workable workaround. [**wordpress-mssql**](http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-mssql/)

Comment: I am having been looking for a plugin and I am not finding anything.  Any plugins that you know of?

Comment: @bvandrunen No. It's probably fair to say that there is, at this point, no way to run Wordpress with MS SQL in a stable manner for a number of reasons that even a magic plugin couldn't solve. Stop wasting your time, and start looking at mySQL.

Answer (score 1):

So we are running Wordpress 3 with MS SQL 2008 under IIS 7 and the Wincache plugin and it's great.  The trick is as another poster suggested is the MySQL that exists in many plugins.  The project is here http://sourceforge.net/projects/wp-sqlsrv/

Answer (score 1):

WordPress won't natively run MSSQL. However, an up-to-date fork that supports MSSQL [does exist](https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami).