# Wordpress with sql in iis 6

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Using wordpress with sql really achievable, whether it will have any limitations for implementing functionalities of a news website in wrodpress with back end database as sql?

i have gone through couple of tutorials like 
http://wordpress.visitmix.com/development/installing-wordpress-on-sql-server but i could not not find any wordpress distribution there. Anybody has experience in using wordpress along with sql if so how can i achieve it?

Comment: Have you had a look here? http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress

Comment: You mean MSSQL right?

Comment: Official support: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-integrate-wordpress-with-ms-sql-server-database

Comment: Also, duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293153/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ms-sql